# How to troubleshoot an management.azure.com rest api call

Tags: azure, rest, azure-management-api

I´m invoking [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools?api-version=2021-07-12](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools?api-version=2021-07-12) and **randomly** fails, returning a "500 Internal Server Error". Is there any way to troubleshoot this obscure error? Any log I can check?

Regards

**EDIT:** I do not provide the source code because this is not a code issue. This restapi call have been working in prod perfectly for months and, two days ago, suddenly it started to fail returning a 500 error in (more or less) 40% of calls. I would like to check some log or whatever in order to know what is happening on behind.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Virtual Desktop troubleshooting steps are documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/troubleshoot-set-up-overview

Not really enough detail in the question to answer anything specific for your environment.

Comment: I have no issues with virtual desktop itself (all things goes, apparently, well). The issue is with the rest api call which should provide me the list of hostpools, it sometimes breaks returning a 500 error

Comment: The cause of the issue has been discovered (if can help somebody) It seems that DC servers were unreachable at certain moments due to network traffic issues, so when the azure management backend tried to validate the auth header of the restapi call, it crashed. This is not really the answer to the question (still waiting to know the logs behind the restapi calls) so I add as a comment.